# Getting Policy Error on connecting to a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is a C# ASP.NET 1.1 WebService and it is on customer's machine, they have given me a Cisco VPN access to their machine so that is how I connect to them.

I have first done this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

and then I am calling their web service

But I get an exception Server 500 error with **Policy Falsified** message.

That is all the information I really have!

What are some things I can try to see if it fixes it?